# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework.simplejwt'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm trying to use simplejwt, but am getting a `ModuleNotFoundError`. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

**requirements.txt**

```
algoliasearch-django>=2.0,<3.0
django>=4.0.0,<4.1.0
djangorestframework
djangorestframework-simplejwt
pyyaml
requests
django-cors-headers
black
isort
```

**settings.py**

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    # third party api services
    "algoliasearch_django",
    # third-party packages
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "rest_framework.simplejwt",
    # internal apps
    "api",
    "products",
    "search",
]

    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
        "api.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly"
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination",
    "PAGE_SIZE": 10}

    SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ["Bearer"],
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": datetime.timedelta(seconds=30),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": datetime.timedelta(minutes=1),
}
```

**Full traceback:**

```
python manage.py runserver

     
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/saulfeliz/Dropbox/macBook/Documents/Learning/drf/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/saulfeliz/Dropbox/macBook/Documents/Learning/drf/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/saulfeliz/Dropbox/macBook/Documents/Learning/drf/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/saulfeliz/Dropbox/macBook/Documents/Learning/drf/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/saulfeliz/Dropbox/macBook/Documents/Learning/drf/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/saulfeliz/Dropbox/macBook/Documents/Learning/drf/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/saulfeliz/Dropbox/macBook/Documents/Learning/drf/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/saulfeliz/Dropbox/macBook/Documents/Learning/drf/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 228, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework.simplejwt'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's `rest_framework_simplejwt` not `rest_framework.simplejwt` as jwt is a separate lib not part of drf